# looping through multiple arrays to transfer information between excel workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

I have written some code that populates a preformatted worksheet in an another workbook, from another preformatted worksheet. They include merged cells and all other things nasty, and for whatever reason cannot be changed.

So, I have written the following

```
Sub test()

Dim wbkCurrent As Workbook
'Dim wbk3Mth As Workbook
Dim wbk6Mth As Workbook

Set wbkCurrent = ThisWorkbook
Set wbk6Mth = Workbooks.Open("C:\newbook.xlsm")

newbook.Sheets("Mon 1").Activate
Call assignArrays

End Sub

Sub assignArrays

Call moveValues(32, 3, 7, 8)
Call moveValues(32, 5, 23, 6)
Call moveValues(32, 65, 15, 8)
Call moveValues(32, 56, 31, 5)
Call moveValues(32, 57, 31, 11)
Call moveValues(32, 15, 39, 4)
Call moveValues(32, 16, 39, 5)
Call moveValues(32, 17, 39, 6)
Call moveValues(32, 18, 39, 7)
Call moveValues(32, 30, 39, 10)
Call moveValues(32, 31, 39, 11)
Call moveValues(32, 32, 39, 12)
Call moveValues(32, 33, 39, 13)

Call moveValues(32, 7, 7, 21)
Call moveValues(32, 9, 23, 19)
Call moveValues(32, 66, 15, 21)
Call moveValues(32, 59, 31, 18)
Call moveValues(32, 60, 31, 24)
Call moveValues(32, 20, 39, 17)
Call moveValues(32, 21, 39, 18)
Call moveValues(32, 22, 39, 19)
Call moveValues(32, 23, 39, 20)
Call moveValues(32, 35, 39, 23)
Call moveValues(32, 36, 39, 24)
Call moveValues(32, 37, 39, 25)
Call moveValues(32, 38, 39, 26)

Call moveValues(32, 11, 7, 34)
Call moveValues(32, 13, 23, 32)
Call moveValues(32, 67, 15, 34)
Call moveValues(32, 62, 31, 31)
Call moveValues(32, 63, 31, 37)
Call moveValues(32, 25, 39, 30)
Call moveValues(32, 26, 39, 31)
Call moveValues(32, 27, 39, 32)
Call moveValues(32, 28, 39, 33)
Call moveValues(32, 40, 39, 36)
Call moveValues(32, 41, 39, 37)
Call moveValues(32, 42, 39, 38)
Call moveValues(32, 43, 39, 39)

End Sub

Sub moveValues(tRow, tCol, rRow, rCol)
'trow is row in this workbook, tcol is column in this workbook, rRow & rCol are the same for the other workbook

ActiveSheet.Cells(rRow, rCol).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Results").Cells(tRow, tCol).Value
tRow = tRow + 1
rRow = rRow + 1
ActiveSheet.Cells(rRow, rCol).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Results").Cells(tRow, tCol).Value
tRow = tRow + 1
rRow = rRow + 1
ActiveSheet.Cells(rRow, rCol).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Results").Cells(tRow, tCol).Value
tRow = tRow + 1
rRow = rRow + 1
ActiveSheet.Cells(rRow, rCol).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Results").Cells(tRow, tCol).Value
tRow = tRow + 1
rRow = rRow + 1
ActiveSheet.Cells(rRow, rCol).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Results").Cells(tRow, tCol).Value
tRow = tRow + 1
rRow = rRow + 1
ActiveSheet.Cells(rRow, rCol).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Results").Cells(tRow, tCol).Value

End Sub
```

This works fine, and writes all the data out. Problem is, I need this to run starting where 
    trow = 2,12,22,32,42,52
Now I could write this all out manually, but it would mean that going in and changing it later would be a nightmare. So, I had the idea of using `a = 2,12,22,32 etc` and then having 
    call moveValues(a, 3, 7, 8)
However this means `a` bumps up a digit through the moveValues subroutine, and needs resetting each time.

I have one idea to solve this using arrays, but that has its own issues.

I replaced the module `assignArrays` with

```
Sub assignArrays()

'row in this workbook
Dim array1(5)
array1(5) = Array(2, 12, 22, 32, 42, 52)

'E
Dim array2(12)
array2(12) = Array(3, 5, 65, 56, 57, 15, 16, 17, 18, 30, 31, 32, 33)

'U
Dim array2_1(12)
array2_1(12) = Array(7, 9, 66, 59, 60, 20, 21, 22, 23, 35, 36, 37, 38)

'R
Dim array2_2(12)
array2_2(12) = Array(11, 13, 67, 62, 63, 25, 26, 27, 28, 40, 41, 42, 43)

'row in report
Dim array3(12)
array3(12) = Array(7, 23, 15, 31, 31, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39) 'constant in each array 1

'column in report
Dim array4(12)
array4(12) = Array(8, 6, 8, 5, 11, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10, 11, 12, 13) '+13 for each third

Dim v1, v2, v3, v4 As Integer

For a = 0 To 5
v1 = array1(a)
    For b = 0 To 12
        v3 = array3(b)
            For c = 0 To 12
                v4 = array4(c)
                    For d = 0 To 12
                        v2 = array2(d)
                        Call moveValues(v1, v2, v3, v4)
                    Next d
            Next c
            For c = 0 To 12
                v4 = array4(c) + 13
                    For d = 0 To 12
                        v2 = array2(d)
                        Call moveValues(v1, v2, v3, v4)
                    Next d
            Next c
            For c = 0 To 12
                v4 = array4(c) + 26
                    For d = 0 To 12
                        v2 = array2(d)
                        Call moveValues(v1, v2, v3, v4)
                    Next d
            Next c
    Next b
Next a
End Sub
```

This dies with a 1004 error on the first line of moveValues. Any ideas to fix either solution?

Comment: Worked out the answer to using `a=2,12,22 etc` - just use `byVal` - still, why won't the array work?

Answer (score 0):

You are not dealing with arrays properly.

```
Dim array1(5) 'Array with 5 dimension
array1(5) = Array(2, 12, 22, 32, 42, 52) 'Write all this content to the fifth position
```

The proper way to do that is:

```
Dim array1(5) As Integer
array1(0) = 2
array1(1) = 12
array1(2) = 22
array1(3) = 32
array1(4) = 42
array1(5) = 52
```

If you want to rely on one line, you can do:

```
Dim array1 
array1 = Array(2, 12, 22, 32, 42, 52) 'In this case, it starts from 0 -> pretty unconventional (bear in mind that the array above is dimensioned from 1)
```

---- UPDATE

What your code delivers:

```
Dim array1(5)
array1(5) = Array(2, 12, 22, 32, 42, 52)

Dim test1 As Integer: test1 = array1(0)  '-> 0
Dim test2 As Integer: test2 = array1(1)  '-> 0
Dim test3 As Integer: test3 = array1(2)  '-> 0
Dim test4 As Integer: test4 = array1(3)  '-> 0
Dim test5 As Integer: test5 = array1(4)  '-> 0
Dim test6 As Integer: test6 = array1(5)  'ERROR
```

What my code delivers:

```
Dim array1 
array1 = Array(2, 12, 22, 32, 42, 52)

Dim test1 As Integer: test1 = array1(0)  '-> 2
Dim test2 As Integer: test2 = array1(1)  '-> 12
Dim test3 As Integer: test3 = array1(2)  '-> 22
Dim test4 As Integer: test4 = array1(3)  '-> 32
Dim test5 As Integer: test5 = array1(4)  '-> 42
Dim test6 As Integer: test6 = array1(5)  '-> 52
```

Comment: THanks - but I'm using 
    `For a = 0 To 5
    v1 = array1(a)`
Doesn't that take it into account? The sub with the arrays being declared works fine, but the values in the array aren't being transferred to `moveValues` sub

Comment: The line array1(5) = Array(2, 12, 22, 32, 42, 52) is, theoretically, wrong (for what you want). I haven't tested it and I am not completely sure about the exact performance but if you are getting an error, why don't write all the code as it is supossed to be written and reduce the possible source of problems? Please tell me the exact line where it crashes and the error you get.

Comment: @OliverLockett I have to partially correct one of my statements. In a discussion with TimWilliams, I understood that user-defined VBA arrays are always zero-based (what is not the case with the in-built property arrays, which are usually 1-based). This fact does not affect the answer I gave you radically (your arrays were wrong and mine are right) but this idea is implicit in the first array declaration I proposed: it is over-dimensioned by 1. I will change it right away. In any case, this does not have any effect on your problem which, I hope, is solved already.